# Hide a subfolder inside a share windows server

Tags: shared-folders, windows-server

Im using windows server 2012 R2 and im trying to hide parts of one share for all users. I still want everybody to read from it if the have the correct path to it.

Lets say all user that have access and have read and write to Share1 and can see all subfolders but I want subfolderB to be hidden for all users in windows explorer (even with show hidden items)
-Share1 (read/write)
-Subfolder (read/write)
-SubfolderA (hidden but all who have access to share1 can read and write to it if they have the proper path to it)

Is this possible?

Comment: Here is a similar thread for your reference, please check if it is helpful to you: https://serverfault.com/questions/886702/how-can-a-user-traverse-directories-to-a-file-but-hide-all-other-items-while-tra

Answer (score 0):

It is almost always better to set up separate Organizational Units for each user management group and give groups access only to their own folders.

This way users can see but not access other folders not in their OU. There has not been any need at our Clients to "hide" folders - just restrict access.

It is very difficult to bury OU groups below a top level folder. This usually does not work and leads to grief.

Make a Common Folder in the Users Shared Folder area of the Server (that everyone can access) and make OU groups directly at the top of "Common" and then assign Users to the proper OU in Active Directory.

This method works at all our clients.